# appendChild is not correct

Tags: javascript, ajax

If I have :

```
<div id="mc"></div>
```

and the following **ajax.responseText** :

```
<div id="mc">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

and finally my Javascript code :

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
var divChildren = div.children;
for(var i = 0; i < divChildren.length; i++) {
  var root = divChildren[i];
  var children = root.children;
  var documentRoot = document.getElementById(root.id||"$");
  if(documentRoot) {
    var node = null;
    for(var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
      node = children[j];
      documentRoot.appendChild(node);
    }
  } 
}
```

**Why does the result is ? :**

```
<div id="mc">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because `children` is a live list, which means when you append one of its elements elsewhere, it will be removed from the list. This messes up forward iteration, unless you decrement the index every time one is removed.

Here are two example solutions...

You would decrement `j`...

```
for(var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
  node = children[j];
  j--;
  documentRoot.appendChild(node);
}
```

But since you're appending all the elements, this doesn't make much sense, since `j` is just bouncing back and forth between `0` and `-1`.

Because  you're adding all the elements, you can simply run the loop as long as there's something at index `0`...

```
while(children[0]) {
  node = children[0];
  documentRoot.appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, "j--" helped, I didn't know about this, that is something new to me.

Comment: You can work backwards through the list, that way removing members doesn't mess up the counter.

Comment: @RobG: But that will reverse the order of the elements in their destination.

Comment: Not if [insertBefore](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) is used: `document.root.insertBefore(node, document.root.firstChild)`. Now each node is inserted before the first child, maintaining the order.

Comment: @RobG: The first iteration would need to be an `.appendChild`, and the subsequent iterations would need to be `.insertBefore` against the `firstChild`. But this also assumes that the container is empty to begin with. If not, then the first iteration is still `.appendChild`, but subsequent iterations would be `insertBefore` the previously inserted element.

Comment: If the container is empty, all operations can be insertBefore as if there is no firstChild (i.e. `refChild` is `null`, per the spec), the node is appended. If the intention is to append after existing children, then all are append after the current lastChild. Or they can be copied to a document fragment and append that (which will be faster than appending them one at a time to the DOM). BTW, the `children` property is part of the DOM 4 draft [Node interface](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-node), so not to be relied on.

Comment: @RobG: Sweet. Didn't know that about `insertBefore`. Thanks!